# AWS IoT topic rule deletion by cloudformation failed with NotStabilized error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot

I have deployed successfully this stack:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  some decription

Parameters:
  ImageUri:
    Type: String

Resources:
  SomeLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      PackageType: Image
      ImageConfig:
        Command: ["src/something"]
      ImageUri: !Ref ImageUri
      Events:
        IoTRule:
          Type: IoTRule
          Properties:
            Sql: SELECT * FROM 'something/+/+'
            AwsIotSqlVersion: 2016-03-23
```

I deploy the above stack as a nested stack of my root stack.

When im trying to delete the stack, the "AWS::IoT::TopicRule" resource gives me a "DELETE IN PROGRESS" status for about 15 minutes and then "DELETE FAILED" status.

The error message on cloudformation is:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Exceeded attempts to wait" (RequestToken: ***********, HandlerErrorCode: NotStabilized)
```

I looked at the cloudformation docs of the error codes(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/resource-type-test-contract-errors.html),
it says that:

```
NotStabilized

The downstream resource failed to complete all of its ready-state checks.

Type: Terminal
```

does anyone know how to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a bypass:

This problem occurred when I attempted to delete the cloudformation stack with python boto3 lib.

later, I tried to use aws-cli to delete the stack - and it was deleted successfully.